# Can't center or "enter" (in the right column) inside a two- (or more-) column translation-tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This article is a follow-up of my old post: [Drawing a vertical line inside a tabular or inside the parallel package (and how to expand parallel to have more than 2 columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/drawing-a-vertical-line-inside-a-tabular-or-inside-the-parallel-package-and-how).

Still, it seems impossible to have

- centered text in the right column
- multiple text lines inside the same "entry" in the right column

The problems are expressed in the following bit of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\svparskip
\newlength\delfix
\delfix1.3pt
\newlength\colwidth
\setlength\colwidth{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\newlength\splitcolwidth
\setlength\splitcolwidth{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\newenvironment{partabular}
  {\par\svparskip=\parskip\relax\vspace{\delfix}}
  {\vspace{\delfix}\parskip=\svparskip\relax}
\newenvironment{nextentry}
  {\parskip-\delfix\par\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]
  {|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|}\hline}{\hline\end{tabular*}\par}
\def\filllines#1{\vspace{\dimexpr#1\ht\strutbox+#1\dp\strutbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{partabular}
\begin{nextentry}
\centering{\textbf{$(A)$ some text i can center}} & {\centering{\textbf{$(B)$ some text i can't center}}} \\\hline
$(C)$ some text here and then enter \\ and have some more text below \\ which is possible & $(D)$ \textbf{some text here but then enter} \\ \textbf{and have some more text below} \\ \textbf{isn't possible + the vertical lines on the right get distorted ...} \\
\end{nextentry}
\begin{nextentry}
$(E)$ & $(F)$ \\\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\splitcolwidth}|p{\splitcolwidth}@{}}
$(H)_1$ \filllines{6}& $(H)_2$
  \end{tabular} 
& \vspace{1cm} Thanks for any help in advance! :) \\
\end{nextentry}
\end{partabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your referenced question is listed under a different (former??) user ID.  Perhaps a moderator can reconcile the differences for you.

Comment: Exactly. It was a first account to try out the site. Actually, I even made another guest-account and with it, I asked one question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216019/vertical-array-inside-multicols-translation-problem). It would be handy if someone could transfer the questions under my active account? The other try-out accounts are now redundant. It would be nice if someone had the powers and the kindness to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are manually extending the vertical in one column, I'm not sure how to automate the process in the other.  But if you can live with manual intervention, you should be able to achieve the vertical layout you want, using `\filllines{}` to manually insert blank lines.

EDITED to achieve horizontal centering in cells B, D, F, and bottom-right cell.  In order for `\centering` to take effect, a `\par` must take effect.  This can be done with `{\centering...\par}` in the last two cases, but because cells "B" and "F" are a single line, I had to achieve it with `\hfil...\hfill`, lest the `\par` produced an unwanted blank line.

To answer the OP's comment on how I vertically centered cell "D", the key was to make cell "C" a single cell, whereas the OP's MWE composes cell "C" as two unique cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\svparskip
\newlength\delfix
\delfix1.3pt
\newlength\colwidth
\setlength\colwidth{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\newlength\splitcolwidth
\setlength\splitcolwidth{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\newenvironment{partabular}
  {\par\svparskip=\parskip\relax\vspace{\delfix}}
  {\vspace{\delfix}\parskip=\svparskip\relax}
\newenvironment{nextentry}
  {\parskip-\delfix\par\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]
  {|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|}\hline}{\hline\end{tabular*}\par}
\def\filllines#1{\vspace{\dimexpr#1\ht\strutbox+#1\dp\strutbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{partabular}
\begin{nextentry}
\centering{\textbf{$(A)$ some text i can center}} 
  & \hfil\bfseries$(B)$ some text i can't center\hfill\\ \hline
$(C)$ some text here and then enter and have some more text below  which is possible\bfseries\par\bigskip
and have some more text below
isn't possible + the vertical lines on the right get distorted ...
&  \filllines{2.5}{\centering$(D)$ \bfseries text here but then enter\par}
\filllines{2} \\ 
\end{nextentry}
\begin{nextentry}
$(E)$ & \hfil$(F)$\hfill \\\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\splitcolwidth}|p{\splitcolwidth}@{}}
$(H)_1$ \filllines{6}& $(H)_2$
  \end{tabular} 
& \filllines{2.5} {\centering Thanks for any help in advance! :)\par} \\
\end{nextentry}
\end{partabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. You solved a problem right away: the vertical lines on the far rightside of the right column are not distorted any longer. How did you achieve that though? --- But the two other problems remain. The first one is that neither (B), nor (D), nor (F) can have centered text. And the second one is that you can't have a line of text in any of those same three sections, and then "enter" and have a new line of text in the same section. (That's what I tried to show with the text from (D): "**Text here but then enter `(2 backslashes)` and have some more text below isn't possible...**"

Comment: @VincentVerheyen Please see revision.

Comment: Off-topic and meta: I just found out how to type two backslashes in code-format on this site (or at least in the comments-section): ``\\``. One has to use two ***backticks*** `''\\''` instead of only one `'\\'`. The last option wouldn't work.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen Thanks for that tip.  I did not ever figure out how to achieve that until now.  I generally left off the backticks for a \\.  Now I can do it as ``\\``

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes I am glad to be able to do something (small; since in the range of my knwoledge) in return. You are getting nice problem-solving results, thanks! The only problem remaining is not being able to enter (e.g. in section (B), (D), or (F)) using ``\\``; e.i. anywhere in the right-hand column.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen  Why do you need a ``\\``?  The columns are type `p` and wrap automatically.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes I guess this can be handy for a specific kind of lay-out, when you want to have a new line of text occasionaly in a table-section before the end of the colum-width is reached. For example if a facsimile edition of a certain work asks for it.